# Proper way of storing user info during PayPal Checkout payment process

Tags: paypal, session-variables

I have a registration website. Tickets can be purchased through PayPal Checkout, but of course in this case users are redirected to PayPal.com to pay there.

Problem: I don't want to write anything in my website's database before payment is complete. I want to write everything when users are back to my website from PayPal checkout page.

Question: what is the proper way of storing user info and purchase info during PayPal Checkout payment process? Is PHP session variables the right, professional response to this problem? Or is there a more reliable solution?

Comment: If you don't store information about the transaction before the payment is complete, how will your site know which payment messages from PayPal go with which transactions?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended method would be to use [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).  It will POST transaction data to a listener script that you build which can receive that data and then update your database, send out email notifications, etc. in real-time.

IPN is separate from your actual checkout flow, though.  It's just a script that sits there listening for data to hit it, and PayPal pushes data to it in real-time as transactions hit your account.

Here's an [IPN template I built years ago](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-paypal-ipn-template/) that would get you up-and-running very quickly.

Comment: Thx Andrew. One question before delving into your IPN template: what's wrong with keeping user & purchase info in session variables during PP checkout and then, once back to the site from PayPal.com, processing this info? Why is IPN better?

Comment: If you're using Payments Standard there is no guarantee the user would ever make it back to your site even with Auto-Return enabled.  If they close their browser before the redirect, for example, they would never reach that page and that code would never run for that order.  If you're using Express Checkout they will end up back on your site prior to completing payment, however, if they pay with e-check or if the payment is pending for any reason you wouldn't want to process it as completed.  IPN will be hit for pending transaction, and again when it completes so you can handle it correctly.